# Continuously prompt the user for the correct input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out a way to ensure the user enters valid input for a personal website project i'm doing. I've been searching for ways to do this for a little while now, but i'm coming up short. In C++, or most other languages I assume, this would be rather simple. For example,

```cpp
string example;
cout << "Enter a number less than 100\n";
cin >> example;

while(example > 100){
   cin >> example;
}
```

This would ensure the user only enters valid information.

With my Javascript/HTML code, i'm getting the initial user input like so,

```
<input id = "example" type="text" placeholder="Enter Here" onchange="foo()">
```

Then in the javascript file, I first attempted to just put an alert inside a while loop, but that doesn't allow the user to input new information since javascript continues on to the next function/part of the code regardless.

I then tried adding an event listener, but i'm still not sure how I get the code to *pause* at that point to ensure the user enters valid information before moving on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript is event driven. You don't ask for input repeatedly, you just do something each time the user enters the input. In this case, the `foo()` function runs.

Comment: I know the foo() function runs, but I want program to pause if the input isn't valid, preferably not even run that function. If there's no way to do this, i'll just have to figure out repeat the input without necessarily looping.

Comment: Generally, in Javascript, you're dealing with HTML forms. The common pattern is to let the user fill out a form, then check it with onsubmit= and if it's invalid, display an error message and prevent the user from continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use loops for this in JavaScript, because the loop can't stop to wait for the user to fill in a field.

Instead, you check whether the ending condition is met in the function that runs when the user enters input into the field. This is the `foo()` function.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("example");
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let message = document.getElementById("prompt");
function foo() {
  let value = parseInt(input.value);
  if (value > 100) {
    message.classList.add("error");
    input.focus();
  } else {
    output.innerText = "Congratulations, you win!";
    input.style.display="none";
    message.classList.remove("error");
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="prompt">Please enter a number below 100:</div>
<input id="example" type="text" placeholder="Enter Here" onchange="foo()">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I'm going to have to restructure a fair bit of my code, but this gave me an idea. Thank you for the explanations

Comment: Web applications are not structured like normal console applications. You need to learn this paradigm.

Comment: Noted, for sure. Thanks again